# Количество узлов в дереве, С++

Tags: бинарное-дерево, алгоритм, дерево, c, c++

Подскажите, каким алгоритмом лучше подсчитать количество узлов в бинарном дереве?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать простую рекурсивную функцию для поиска числа узлов. Она будет возвращать сумму узлов левого поддерева и правого поддерева плюс один (сам узел).

```
int NodeCount(BinaryTreeNode * node)
{
    if (node->leftChild == NULL && node->rightChild == NULL)
        return 1;
    int left, right;
    if (node->leftChild != NULL)
        left = NodeCount(node->leftChild);
    else
        left = 0;
    if (node->rightChild != NULL)
        right = NodeCount(node->rightChild); 
    else 
        right = 0;

    return left+right+1;
}
```